# Probability that the student knows correct answer

Tags: probability

The probability that a student knows the correct answer to a test is 1/4 . If the student doesn't know the answer he guesses the answer, four possible answers on test. Given that the student did not answer correctly (his answer was wrong), what's the probability that the student knows the correct answer?
Let

a = student knows the correct answer

b = guessed answer is wrong

P(a)=1/4 P(a')=3/4

P(b)= ??

How do I proceed?

Comment: Use bayes thm.....

Answer (score 1):

$$P(b)=P(b\mid a)P(a)+P(b\mid a^{\complement})P(a^{\complement})$$